# Error in Visual Studio when I debug my app

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Every day after a few builds in C++ with Visual Studio 2022 Preview, I get this error 
[image: [image]]

*Translation: The application failed to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.* 
It's very annoying because I have to restart my PC ... Do you have any support to stop this?

Comment: Probably either malware or “antivirus” software.

Comment: Search for the error message online, I'd suggest. It would be easier to find if you didn't use an image but copied the text instead, btw. If that doesn't help, ask yourself if anyone here could tell you what is wrong with a program only have seen? Please provide a [mcve] instead!

Comment: I have this error in console `The program '[30320] init_new_module.exe' has exited with code 3221225794 (0xc0000142) 'DLL Initialization Failed'.`

Comment: Don't forget that you are using a Preview / Release candidate.

Comment: You could refer to this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352248/any-ideas-on-how-to-fix-a-dll-initialization-error-in-visual-studio-2019).